# Rolling sum in subgroups of a dataframe (pandas)

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I have `sessions` dataframe that contains `E-mail` and `Sessions` (int) columns.

I need to calculate rolling sum of sessions *per email* (i.e. not globally).

Now, the following works, but it's painfully slow:

```
emails = set(list(sessions['E-mail']))
ses_sums = []
for em in emails:
    email_sessions = sessions[sessions['E-mail'] == em]
    email_sessions.is_copy = False
    email_sessions['Session_Rolling_Sum'] = pd.rolling_sum(email_sessions['Sessions'], window=self.window).fillna(0)
    ses_sums.append(email_sessions)
df = pd.concat(ses_sums, ignore_index=True)
```

Is there a way of achieving the same in `pandas`, but using `pandas` operators on a dataframe instead of creating separate dataframes for each email and then concatenating them?

(either that or some other way of making this faster)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Setup**

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame({'E-Mail': np.random.choice(list('AB'), 20),
                   'Session': np.random.randint(1, 10, 20)})
```

**Solution**

The current and proper way to do this is with `rolling.sum` that can b used on the result of a `pd.Series` group by object.

```
#      Series Group By
# /------------------------\
df.groupby('E-Mail').Session.rolling(3).sum()
#                            \--------------/
#                             Method you want

E-Mail    
A       0      NaN
        2      NaN
        4     11.0
        5      7.0
        7     10.0
        12    16.0
        15    16.0
        17    16.0
        18    17.0
        19    18.0
B       1      NaN
        3      NaN
        6     18.0
        8     14.0
        9     16.0
        10    12.0
        11    13.0
        13    16.0
        14    20.0
        16    22.0
Name: Session, dtype: float64
```

**Details**

```
df

   E-Mail  Session
0       A        9
1       B        7
2       A        1
3       B        3
4       A        1
5       A        5
6       B        8
7       A        4
8       B        3
9       B        5
10      B        4
11      B        4
12      A        7
13      B        8
14      B        8
15      A        5
16      B        6
17      A        4
18      A        8
19      A        6
```

Comment: How does 0 + 2 + 4 = 11?

Comment: @Blake I don't know. How?  If you are referring to the index values, look at the where the first 3 values of `'E-Mail'` are equal to `'A'`.  You'll see that the index values are `0`, `2`, and `4`.  Those index values get embedded into the second level of a Pandas `MultiIndex`.  `11` is the result of `9 + 1 + 1` .

Comment: Yes I was confused as to what .rolling() does. I thought it was .cumsum() but it is just a windowed aggregation. I see now

Answer (score 3):

Say you start with

```
In [58]: df = pd.DataFrame({'E-Mail': ['foo'] * 3 + ['bar'] * 3 + ['foo'] * 3, 'Session': range(9)})

In [59]: df
Out[59]: 
  E-Mail  Session
0    foo        0
1    foo        1
2    foo        2
3    bar        3
4    bar        4
5    bar        5
6    foo        6
7    foo        7
8    foo        8

In [60]: df[['Session']].groupby(df['E-Mail']).apply(pd.rolling_sum, 3)
Out[60]: 
          Session
E-Mail           
bar    3      NaN
       4      NaN
       5     12.0
foo    0      NaN
       1      NaN
       2      3.0
       6      9.0
       7     15.0
       8     21.0
```

Incidentally, note that I just rearranged your `rolling_sum`, but it has been deprecated - you should now use [`rolling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html):

```
df[['Session']].groupby(df['E-Mail']).apply(lambda g: g.rolling(3).sum())
```

Comment: okay but what is the point of making the first two NaN?  Why not have the rolling sum for bar print 3, 7, 12, and foo print 0,1,3, etc. ?